# iOS: static sectionHeaderView for tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

**Background:** I have implemented a standard tableView that has 4 sections. Each of the section contains a custom view for the header. Normally, the previous header will be pushed away when the header below is scrolled to the top of the tableView.

**Question:** Is it possible to prevent that "pushed out" behavior. I would like something along the line of "stacking" behavior. This is because I would like the user to have the full view of what headers are available. For example, if one scroll to the lowest cell, one will see all headers on the top of the tableView.

**Additional Info:** Please do not answer with hacks, for example, track the movement of the tableView, add the header view manually when needed, then resize the tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible without using methods like you describe. At least not with the built-in table view.

One reason is that it just doesn't scale to arbitrary content. If you let section headers stack up what should happen when the entire screen is full of headers? How would the user be able to comfortably see and interact with the content under the 6th or 7th section when there is only a few pixels left to show the content because the rest of the screen is taken up by header for sections that the user is obviously not interested in.

You probably want to rethink your UI. Either go with the standard section headers, make some cool light-weight tabs, a custom harmonica control or something entirely different. Maybe even a hierarchical structure depending on the amount of content you want to present.

Comment: That is what I am afraid of, I was hoping maybe Apple has some built in ways of doing it. I understand your logic. If I have arbitrary number of section, that would cause a problem. That is why I said 4 sections. Wait around a bit, maybe some people have other insights, else I will mark this correct.